# Issue with the R function rep()

Tags: r

I am having an issue with the R function **rep** or maybe its something simpler that I am doing wrong.

```
    k = ((100)*(1-0.9))
    k # k = 10
    length(rep(0,times = k)) # length of 9 instead of 10
    length(rep(0,times = 10) # length of 10 !
```

This is really weird as the variable k has 10 as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a closer look at `k`.  It's not an integer and it's also not really 10.

```
typeof(k)
# [1] "double"
print(k, digits = 22)
# [1] 9.999999999999998223643
```

We care about `k` being integer valued because the `times` argument of `rep()` should be an integer.  Furthermore, from `help(rep)`:

> Non-integer values of `times` will be truncated towards zero.

So `k` becomes

```
trunc(k)
# [1] 9
```

See the link @Gregor left in the comments for why `k` is not really 10.